# Collision detection by sliding against a plane in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I am attempting to engineer a collision detection algorithm for a custom Minecraft client I'm making. Basically, the entire world is made up of cubes, and the player (or camera) needs to be able to stand on and move against these cubes. The result I want is illustrated in this image:
[image]

The green line is the player's movement vector. When the player is brushing up against a plane of one of the cubes, I want the vector to change to one that is perpendicular with the plane. The vector should, however, keep all of it's velocity in the plane's direction, yet lose all velocity towards the plane.

I hope I've made my question clear. What is the best and most efficient way to implement a collision detection system like this? Also, will a system like this allow for a simple gravity component?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the cubes are stored in a three-dimensional array, [x,y,z].

Comment: I love this question.  I'd suggest that you also post on gamedev.stackexchange.com.  I imagine this to be a common issue in game development.

Comment: @BigDave - Oh, I didn't know there was a site specifically for game development. Stack Exchange really is growing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to implementing this would be to detect the collision of the ball and the plane. Calculate the penetration depth, this is how far the ball has actually gone past the plane, and push the ball back in the direction of the plane's normal.

This will have the effect of putting the ball on the surface of the plane. If you do this for each frame, the ball will effectively slide along the plane, assuming of course that the ball's velocity vector is not not parallel to the plane's normal.

The field of collision detection is big and complex, and depending on your game you have to determine what is sufficient for your requirements in terms of the level of realism you require and the performance requirements. You should always go for the simplest solution that give a realistic enough feedback, depending on the game it often does not have to be perfect.

Basically you should break your collision detection into 2 phases typically known as broad phase and narrow phase.

The broad phase could be as simple as perform a quick bounding box check to determine potential collisions and then submit those potential collision to the narrow phase collision detection to do the more detailed checks where you determine if there really was a collision and the collision depth. If you have many objects then the broad phase might use some kind of quadtree indexing to select only the blocks in the vicinity of your object to perform the collision detection against.

Comment: @Chris Taylor - Yes, I thought it might be something as simple as that. How do you think I should go about calculating it? Should I just iterate through a subset of cubes and check if the player is intersecting with one of them?

Comment: @Bevin, my reply to your extra question got a little long, so I just updated the answer with a little more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Chris Taylor - Well, I know the size of the player, so I could simply iterate over the cubes that are, say, at most 4 blocks away. That should give enough space for detection. How do I detect how far the player has intersected, and how much to push him out of the block?

Comment: @bevin, is your player also a box? If so you want to look at box-box intersection, or what ever shape best approximates you player shape.

Comment: @Chris Taylor - Well, I was just planning on having the player represented by a point, and then use the distance from that point to check collisions.

Comment: It would reduce accuracy a little to remove penetration along the plane's normal. Better to use a standard xna ray at the beginning of the frame to measure distance from player point to plane. Then, if distance is less than a frame's movement distance (velocity length), only move player the lesser distance... Then calculate the new velocity along the plane and finish frame by moving player the remainder of distance along new velocity. New velocity can be calculated by old velocity, plane normal & the standard xna DotProduct method.

Comment: newVelocity = oldVelocity + (planeNormal * Vecor3.Dot(planeNormal, oldVelocity));

Answer (score 0):

In a world of Axis Aligned cubes, this is really easy. It's easy to think that you need something elaborate, but in reality it's really simple. This is from experience after writing my own minecraft clone.

Here's how:

```
position.X += velocity.X;
if(colliding())
  position.X -= velocity.X;

position.Y += velocity.Y;
if(colliding())
  position.Y -= velocity.Y;

position.Z += velocity.Z;
if(colliding())
  position.Z -= velocity.Z;
```

Here's the code for finding out if you're colliding or not:

```
bool colliding()
{
  int minX = Position.X - size.X / 2;
  int minY = Position.Y - size.Y / 2;
  int minZ = Position.Z - size.Z / 2;

  int maxX = Position.X + size.X / 2;
  int maxY = Position.Y + size.Y / 2;
  int maxZ = Position.Z + size.Z / 2;

  for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
    for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
      for (int z = minZ; z <= maxZ; z++)
      {
        if(blockType[x, y, z] != 0)
          return true;
      }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the player isn't aligned. What if the player only slightly intersects one of the planes? Then he will be shoved out further than necessary.

Comment: The player can be treated as a non-rotationg axis aligned box for the sake of collision. It works fine. I know what you mean, but it is not noticable by the player. I'd encourage the OP to give it a try.